# How do I calculate single variable confidence intervals assuming different distributions with R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I'm trying to convert a bunch of Stata commands to their R equivalents, and I'm struggling with how R does handle confidence intervals for inferential statistics of single variables.

In Stata, I can use `ci variable` to calculate normal confidence intervals, `ci variable, b` to calculate binomial intervals, and `ci variable, p` to calculate the intervals assuming the variable is distributed as Poisson.

R seems slightly more complicated, though (`confint()` only works with models…). It appears that I have to run the respective tests to get the confidence intervals (`t.test`, `binom.test`, and `poisson.test`). I'm fine doing that, but these functions seem to be less generalized than Stata's `ci` command.

For example, to calculate a normal 95% confidence interval I use `t.test`:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(100)
t.test(x)

# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -0.35605755  0.04253406
```

However, it seems to be a lot more complicated to calcuate binomial or Poisson intervals. For example, if I have a column of binary data (yes/no; 1/0) like `x` below, Stata appears to convert it into count data automatically when running `ci x, b`. In R, I have to convert it to count data on my own with `sum()`:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE)  # lots of 0s and 1s
binom.test(sum(x), length(x))

# 95 percent confidence interval:
# 0.3503202 0.5527198
```

Is manually feeding in the sum and the length of the variable the official R-esque way of calculating the confidence interval assuming a binomial distribution, or is there a better way?

Likewise, what's the most R-esque way to calculate confidence intervals for a variable assumed to follow a Poisson distribution--the equivalent of `ci x, p`:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rpois(100, 5)  # random Poisson distribution
# ... magic R voodoo ...
# Confidence interval!
```

So, I guess in summary, what's the best R equivalent for Stata's `ci x`, `ci x, b`, and `ci x, p` commands for single variables?

Comment: I really prefer the R framework. There are many ways to construct a confidence interval for a Gaussian mean, a confidence interval for a binomial proportion, a confidence interval for a Poisson rate... For example the binom.test() function provides the Clopper-Pearson binomial test with its associated confidence interval, as shown by ?binom.test. And there is no reason to impose a "default" confidence interval to statisticians who want to understand what they are doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to do a regression of your variable on just an intercept, i.e.

```
x <- rpois(100, 5) 
glm1 <- glm(x~1, family=poisson)
confint(glm1) # or confint.default(), if you want less-clever intervals
```

This gives a confidence interval for the log of the mean of the X's. If you want a confidence interval around something else, either use the `link` argument in your `family=` statement, or transform the interval provided by the code above, e.g.

```
exp(confint(glm1))
```

As Stéphane notes, there's also the `poisson.test()` function. Its syntax is a little removed from typical regression functions, and for this example works out to be;

```
poisson.test(sum(x), 100)
```

In large samples there will be little difference between the methods given.

Comment: We could prefer poisson.test() which provides an "exact" confidence interval (similarly to binom.test() for a binomial proportion)

Comment: So how would you use `poisson.test()` with the x given in this answer (`rpois(100, 5)`? This seems overly complicated and wrong: `poisson.test(as.integer(mean(x)))`